# Pentaho - PDI: get fields of stream

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Pretty simple question here: If I read a .csv file for example, how can I know at runtime what columns that file has?
I want to convert that .csv file to JSON, but I don't know how could I set the fields for the JSON Output step dynamically, to include all the rows of that file. Can you help me expand my knowledge?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a good use case for metadata injection. The step specifically is called `ETL Metadata Injection`. You'll need to get the fields dynamically probably using a scripting step (there's Java, JavaScript, and Python scripting steps available, as well as R if you're an Enterprise customer). I don't think that there is a built in step that will dynamically discover the fields at runtime.

Once you have fields, you can use the metadata injection step to inject the field names into CSV Input or Text File Input Step, as well as the JSON Output step.

Here is the official help documentation on the `ETL Metadata Injection` step: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/ETL_Metadata_Injection

Comment: sounds great, one conceptual thing I don't understand yet:
What do I put at the _Fields_ table of the CSV Input?
The fields coming out of my CSV Input will always be there, despite of being undeclared? Or I'll have to read the file in the JavaScript step as well and inject the fields that way?